# Ping works, SSH and other services not, how to debug?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, debug

So ping worked but SSH and other services were not responding (apache2, etc). I had to do an **hard reboot** of the server and now **things work**, i can connect to SSH and the web server also is fine.

How can I debug this after the reboot?  I am on Debian 7.10 (Wheezy) with root

If i inspect `/var/log/messages` I find that **there is a hole between 14:36 and 14:53** (at 14:53 i did the hard reboot). You can find the messages at 14.36 here:

```
Dec  2 14:36:11 nsserver kernel: apache2 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x3000d0, order=2, oom_score_adj=0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: apache2 cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 19242 Comm: apache2 Tainted: G        W    3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #7
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Hardware name: OVH SP/DG31PR, BIOS PRG3110H.86A.0071.2010.0318.1704 03/18/2010
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: 0000000000000000 ffffc9000516baf0 ffffffff81efbbb8 0000000000000007
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: ffff880129678000 ffffc9000516bb90 ffffffff81ef504f ffffc9000516bb30
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: ffffffff81136cc7 0000000000000000 ffff8800abafde50 ffff8800abafde68
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Call Trace:
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81efbbb8>] dump_stack+0x46/0x58
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81ef504f>] dump_header+0x75/0x1ea
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81136cc7>] ? ktime_get_ts+0x47/0xe0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81158134>] ? delayacct_end+0x84/0xa0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff8169faa6>] ? ___ratelimit+0x96/0x110
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81169b81>] oom_kill_process+0x201/0x350
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff810f4612>] ? has_capability_noaudit+0x12/0x20
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff8116a2cc>] out_of_memory+0x41c/0x510
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff8116fb06>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x776/0x810
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81165f62>] ? unlock_page+0x62/0x70
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff810e9674>] copy_process.part.47+0x124/0x17d0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff816b31e1>] ? __list_del_entry+0x11/0x30
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff816b3211>] ? list_del+0x11/0x30
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81136cc7>] ? ktime_get_ts+0x47/0xe0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff811cf7d8>] ? poll_select_copy_remaining+0x138/0x280
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff810eaee9>] do_fork+0xd9/0x310
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff811d090b>] ? SyS_select+0x12b/0x1b0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff810eb1a1>] SyS_clone+0x11/0x20
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81f05b35>] stub_clone+0x65/0x90
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: [<ffffffff81f0589e>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Mem-Info:
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: active_anon:28548 inactive_anon:28612 isolated_anon:32
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: active_file:295 inactive_file:425 isolated_file:0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:120 unstable:0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: free:501981 slab_reclaimable:117091 slab_unreclaimable:218928
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: mapped:85 shmem:14 pagetables:14224 bounce:0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: free_cma:0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15432kB min:28kB low:32kB high:40kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:256kB slab_unreclaimable:36kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3212 3915 3915
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:1724844kB min:6556kB low:8192kB high:9832kB active_anon:74240kB inactive_anon:74456kB active_file:740kB inactive_file:940kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3379436kB managed:3290224kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:260kB mapped:204kB shmem:52kB slab_reclaimable:419520kB slab_unreclaimable:625416kB kernel_stack:296448kB pagetables:29336kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:10388 all_unreclaimable? yes
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 702 702
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 Normal free:267648kB min:1432kB low:1788kB high:2148kB active_anon:39952kB inactive_anon:39992kB active_file:440kB inactive_file:760kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):128kB isolated(file):0kB present:786432kB managed:719824kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:220kB mapped:136kB shmem:4kB slab_reclaimable:48588kB slab_unreclaimable:250260kB kernel_stack:5168kB pagetables:27560kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:7288 all_unreclaimable? yes
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 1*8kB (U) 0*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB (U) 0*128kB 2*256kB (UE) 1*512kB (E) 2*1024kB (UE) 2*2048kB (UE) 2*4096kB (MR) = 15432kB
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 140964*4kB (EM) 144937*8kB (EM) 95*16kB (M) 1*32kB (R) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 1724904kB
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Node 0 Normal: 57353*4kB (EM) 4777*8kB (EM) 4*16kB (M) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 267692kB
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: 1351 total pagecache pages
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: 568 pages in swap cache
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Swap cache stats: add 909368, delete 908800, find 1781721897/1781923273
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: Total swap = 523260kB
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: 1045465 pages RAM
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: 16652 pages reserved
Dec  2 14:36:16 nsserver kernel: 0 pages hwpoisoned
...
```

Here’s the complete log: https://pastebin.com/hrQM5GmB

Comment: `dmesg` missing is very strange, but it wouldn’t help anyway. It cannot look into the past, only display kernel’s log buffer since rebooting. You must investigate your system’s log files.

Comment: @DanielB: thanks daniel! can you be more specific on the log files i need to investiage? and what i have to look for ?  Anyway I have added more info in first post, and also i have pasted hte last messages i found in var/log/messages here: https://pastebin.com/hrQM5GmB

Comment: @giò depends on your logging service. Since it's debian 7, you probably have `syslog-ng`, thus dig into these: `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/error`, `/var/log/messages`. Older records can be in rotated log files in the same folder.

Comment: Well, as you can see in the log, Apache has been killed by the kernel’s out-of-memory recovery mechanism. You seem to be using something like the prefork MPM module. Consider changing that. You also have a lot of `sh` instances running, why is that? Is your web server perhaps serving CGI scripts?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess apache was pseudorandom :-) victim of OOM killer. Gap in log is likely because syslog was not working - it might have crashed or blocked for some reason or has been killed too. My bet is that something filled up one of the filesystems (/var ? /temp ? maybe some other) or memory. Do you use tmpfs ?

Programs may create files and remove reference from directory while they are still opened. This keeps space allocated on disk until file is closed by process (obviously after reboot you won't see that).

SSH will malfunction if there is no free space to write data to file system or it can't allocate more memory - I'm not sure about details but I know it will stop working under certain conditions. It is important here to be precise. When you tried to open connection to ssh - was TCP connection opening ? Or not even that ?

**Bottom line is that it was run-time issue and after reboot it may be hard to diagnose. Simply kernel was running (machine was responding to ping) but no user space program could do anything. There are a lot of reasons this could have happened; some are more likely, some less. It is unlikely though that it was due to hacker attack.**

Solution is:
If it happens again look at the console before killing machine. Leave opened session if you can. Start monitoring cpu/disk/memory to another machine. Send syslog output to external machine - this way you'll be able to see log entries even if local fs is full.

PS. There is tiny chance that something happened to kernel but that you would surely see from the console before restart.